# How to make components consist between pages?

Tags: next.js

When you go to about page from index page, RestOfTheApp rerenders. Maybe it should be this way with SSR, but nextjs added static rendering like gatsby. Isn't there a way to prevent components rerendering? Like: a header shouldn't change between pages.

about.js

```
function index() {
  return (
    <>
        <RestOfTheApp> 
          about
        </RestOfTheApp>
    </>
  )
}
```

index.js

```
 function index() {
      return (
        <>
        <RestOfTheApp> 
          index
        </RestOfTheApp>
        </>
      )
    }
```

You can keep component state with redux I assume, but whole page re-rendering when you just need to fetch some blog content seems bloaty. I've tested with some basic layout, it still seems lightning fast but not re-rendering whole page is the main concept of SPA's, I am a little heart broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every component that you include in a page (under `/pages`) will re-render no matter what you do. But it's definitely possible to add a persistent layout which doesn't re-render in NextJs. The solution is the custom app component. You can read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Following example can be helpful to understand how you can create a persistent layout:

```
// /pages/_app.js

import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps}></Component>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

In this case, the `Layout` component will not re-render when you navigate between pages.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've just made a header component that consists between pages. Nextjs is kinda weird but i liked it

Comment: Thanks a lot! This definitely should be the accepted answer @AliMertCakar

Answer (score 5):

@Ankit has already given a great answer on HOW to create a persistent component. Here is WHY it works.

So what really happens when you navigate from some page A (defined in `pages/a.js`) to another page B (defined in `pages/b.js`)? First, the navigation takes place on the client-side. This means instead of fetching the rendered HTML from the server, some JavaScript is run in the browser to render the new page. (You can verify it [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages/client-side).) The JavaScript logic of page navigation boils down to this:

1. The JavaScript code of the new page component `<B />` is fetched from the server, if it's not already prefetched;
2. Next.js will call `ReactDOM.render()` with 2 arguments: the first one is the new React element to render (it can be roughly thought of as the updated `App` component), and the second one is the DOM container element (it's always `<div id="__next"></div>`) that the new React element is rendered into.

In short, this process can be roughly thought of as rendering the updated `App` component into the `<div id="__next"></div>` DOM container element. React will then take care of diffing the new and old React elements and decide which part of the DOM to re-render and which part to update.

So what does the new and old React element look like? Well, the default definition of the `App` component looks like this:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Component will be set to the current page component
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Where the `Component` variable will be set to the current page component. This means the old React element will look like this:

```js
<A {...pageProps} />
```

and the new React element will look like this:

```js
<B {...pageProps} />
```

According to the [React diffing algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), when comparing the new and old React element, if the two elements being compared are of different types, then the corresponding subtree will be entirely destroyed and re-rendered.

That's exactly what happens in this case. `<A />` and `<B />` are two different components and are considered as of different types, so the part of the DOM that corresponds to `<A />` will be destroyed and re-rendered as `<B />`.

That's why the entire page component will be re-rendered when you navigate to a new page, even if they include common components like the header.

If you put the header in the custom `App` components, like this:

```js
import Header from '../components/header'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Then the `<Header />` component will persist across page navigations, because the React diffing algorithm will consider it as the same type and will only make minimal updates to the subtree.

Comment: Extremely high quality answer, kudos and cheers!